# JavaScript XML parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

the xml

```
<publication_date media_type="print">
        <month>1</month>
        <year>2011</year>
</publication_date>
```

I have used this code to get title

```
var year = $xml.find('publication_date year').text();
```

but sometimes the xml contains two different types like this:

```
<publication_date media_type="print">
        <month>05</month>
        <day>22</day>
        <year>2012</year>
</publication_date>
<publication_date media_type="online">
        <month>04</month>
        <day>26</day>
        <year>2012</year>
</publication_date>
```

I want to select the year witch comes with `online` `media-type` and if there is no `online` select `print` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simple, use an attribute selector:

```
$xml.find("publication_date[media_type=online] year").text()
```